# Why this recursive function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have seen too many questions that have same problem as mine, but everywhere I see that the problem is that they are not using return keyword when calling the function. So, please don't mark it as duplicate.

Here is my recursive function:

```
function checkSchema(fields, schema) {

    console.log(schema.hasOwnProperty('schema'));
    if (schema.hasOwnProperty('schema')) {
        Object.keys(schema.schema).forEach(function (key) {
        // for (const key in schema.schema) {

            const innerSchema = schema.schema[key];

            if (key === 'custom') {

                if (typeof innerSchema === 'function') {
                    const result = innerSchema(fields);
                    if (result !== null) {
                        console.log('4');
                        return result;
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log('5');
                    return notAFunction;
                }

            } else {

                if (innerSchema.hasOwnProperty('required') && innerSchema.required 
                        && (fields[key] === undefined || fields === null)) {
                            console.log('6');
                            return sendError(innerSchema, 'required');
                }

                if (innerSchema.hasOwnProperty('type')) {

                    if (innerSchema.type !== (fields[key] === undefined ? undefined : fields[key].constructor)) {
                        if (fields[key] === undefined) {
                            if (innerSchema.hasOwnProperty('required') && innerSchema.required) {
                                console.log('7');
                                return sendError(innerSchema, 'type');
                            }
                        } else {
                            console.log('8');
                            return sendError(innerSchema, 'type');
                        }
                    }

                    if (innerSchema.type === Array || innerSchema.type === String) {

                        if (innerSchema.hasOwnProperty('len') && innerSchema.len.constructor === String) {

                            const arrLen = innerSchema.len.split(',');
                            let flag = true; 
                            let el = null;
                            let tempElement = null;
                            const trim = innerSchema.type === String && innerSchema.hasOwnProperty('trim') && innerSchema.trim;

                            arrLen.forEach((element) => {
                                if (element.startsWith('-')) {
                                    el = element.substring(1);
                                    tempElement = isNaN(Number(el)) ? 0 : Number(el);
                                    if (trim ? fields[key].trim().length <= tempElement : fields[key].length <= tempElement) {
                                        flag = false;
                                        return;
                                    }
                                } else if (element.endsWith('-')) {
                                    el = element.substring(0, element.length - 1);
                                    tempElement = isNaN(Number(el)) ? 0 : Number(el);
                                    if (trim ? fields[key].trim().length >= tempElement : fields[key].length >= tempElement) {
                                        flag = false;
                                        return;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    el = element;
                                    tempElement = isNaN(Number(el)) ? 0 : Number(el);
                                    if (trim ? fields[key].trim().length === tempElement : fields[key].length === tempElement) {
                                        flag = false;
                                        return;
                                    }
                                }
                            }, this);

                            if (flag) {
                                console.log('9');
                                return sendError(innerSchema, 'len');
                            }

                        }

                        if (innerSchema.type === Array && innerSchema.hasOwnProperty('unique') 
                                && innerSchema.unique && (new Set(fields[key])).size !== fields[key].length) {
                                    console.log('10');
                                    return sendError(innerSchema, 'unique');
                        }

                        if (innerSchema.type === String && innerSchema.hasOwnProperty('match') 
                                && innerSchema.match instanceof RegExp && !innerSchema.match.test(fields[key])) {
                                    console.log('11');
                                    return sendError(innerSchema, 'match');
                        }

                    }

                    if ((innerSchema.type === Array || innerSchema.type === Object) && innerSchema.hasOwnProperty('schema')) {
                        console.log('12');
                        return checkSchema(fields[key], innerSchema);
                    }

                } 

            }
        });
    }
    console.log('13');    
}
```

Here is the `sendError` function used inside `checkSchema()`:

```
function sendError(schema, prop) {
    const error = schema.errors === undefined ? undefined : schema.errors[prop];
    return (error || defaultError);
}
```

Here is how I call my recursive function:

```
const x = checkSchema(fields, schema);
console.log(x);
```

**Extra Details if someone needs it:**

```
const notAFunction = {
    errorCode: '9999',
    message: 'Not a function'
};

const defaultError = {
    errorCode: '9999',
    message: 'Error message not specified'
};
```

Here is the data that I am passing to this function:

value of fields is:

```
{
    first_name: 'Vishal',
    last_name: 'Sherathiya',
    phone: 9978259999,
    email: 'vishalsherathiya@gmail.com',
    password: '1234567',
    confirm_password: '1234567',
    friends: {
      name: 'ab',
      alias: 'a'
    }
  }
```

value of schema:

```
{
    type: Object,
    unknownKeys: 'allow',
    required: true,
    schema: {
        first_name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            match: /^.{1,}$/,
            errors: {
                type: {
                    errorCode: errorCodes.INVALID_DATA_TYPE,
                    message: errorMessages.FIRST_NAME_INVALID_DT
                },
                required: {
                    errorCode: errorCodes.REQUIRED_FIELD,
                    message: errorMessages.FIRST_NAME_REQUIRED
                },
                match: {
                    errorCode: errorCodes.REQUIRED_FIELD,
                    message: errorMessages.FIRST_NAME_REQUIRED
                },
                allowNull: {
                    errorCode: errorCodes.REQUIRED_FIELD,
                    message: errorMessages.FIRST_NAME_REQUIRED
                }
            }
        },
        last_name: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            required: true,
            match: /^.{1,}$/,
            errors: {
                type: {
                    errorCode: errorCodes.INVALID_DATA_TYPE,
                    message: errorMessages.LAST_NAME_INVALID_DT
                },
                required: {
                    errorCode: errorCodes.REQUIRED_FIELD,
                    message: errorMessages.LAST_NAME_REQUIRED
                },
                match: {
                    errorCode: errorCodes.REQUIRED_FIELD,
                    message: errorMessages.LAST_NAME_REQUIRED
                },
                allowNull: {
                    errorCode: errorCodes.REQUIRED_FIELD,
                    message: errorMessages.LAST_NAME_REQUIRED
                }
            }
        },
        phone: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            match: /^.{1,}$/,
            errors: {
                type: {
                    errorCode: errorCodes.INVALID_DATA_TYPE,
                    message: errorMessages.PHONE_INVALID_DT
                },
                required: {
                    errorCode: errorCodes.REQUIRED_FIELD,
                    message: errorMessages.PHONE_REQUIRED
                },
                match: {
                    errorCode: errorCodes.REQUIRED_FIELD,
                    message: errorMessages.PHONE_REQUIRED
                },
                allowNull: {
                    errorCode: errorCodes.REQUIRED_FIELD,
                    message: errorMessages.PHONE_REQUIRED
                }
            }
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            required: true,
            match: /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
            errors: {
                type: {
                    errorCode: errorCodes.INVALID_DATA_TYPE,
                    message: errorMessages.EMAIL_INVALID_DT
                },
                required: {
                    errorCode: errorCodes.REQUIRED_FIELD,
                    message: errorMessages.EMAIL_REQUIRED
                },
                match: {
                    errorCode: errorCodes.INVALID_VALUE,
                    message: errorMessages.EMAIL_INVALID_VALUE
                },
                allowNull: {
                    errorCode: errorCodes.REQUIRED_FIELD,
                    message: errorMessages.EMAIL_REQUIRED
                }
            }
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            required: true,
            match: /^.{1,}$/,
            errors: {
                type: {
                    errorCode: errorCodes.INVALID_DATA_TYPE,
                    message: errorMessages.PASSWORD_INVALID_DT
                },
                required: {
                    errorCode: errorCodes.REQUIRED_FIELD,
                    message: errorMessages.PASSWORD_REQUIRED
                },
                match: {
                    errorCode: errorCodes.REQUIRED_FIELD,
                    message: errorMessages.PASSWORD_REQUIRED
                },
                allowNull: {
                    errorCode: errorCodes.REQUIRED_FIELD,
                    message: errorMessages.PASSWORD_REQUIRED
                }
            }
        },
        confirm_password: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            required: true,
            match: /^.{1,}$/,
            errors: {
                type: {
                    errorCode: errorCodes.INVALID_DATA_TYPE,
                    message: errorMessages.CONFIRM_PASSWORD_INVALID_DT
                },
                required: {
                    errorCode: errorCodes.REQUIRED_FIELD,
                    message: errorMessages.CONFIRM_PASSWORD_REQUIRED
                },
                match: {
                    errorCode: errorCodes.REQUIRED_FIELD,
                    message: errorMessages.CONFIRM_PASSWORD_REQUIRED
                },
                allowNull: {
                    errorCode: errorCodes.REQUIRED_FIELD,
                    message: errorMessages.CONFIRM_PASSWORD_REQUIRED
                }
            }
        },
        friends: {
            type: Object,
            schema: {
                name: {
                    type: String,
                    required: true,
                    len: '2', 
                    errors: {
                        type: {
                            errorCode: errorCodes.INVALID_DATA_TYPE,
                            message: errorMessages.FRIEND_NAME_INVALID_DT
                        },
                        required: {
                            errorCode: errorCodes.REQUIRED_FIELD,
                            message: errorMessages.FRIEND_NAME_REQUIRED
                        },
                        len: {
                            errorCode: errorCodes.LENGTH_MISMATCH,
                            message: errorMessages.FRIENDS_NAME_LENGTH
                        }
                    }    
                },
                alias: {
                    type: String,
                    required: true,
                    len: '2',
                    errors: {
                        type: {
                            errorCode: errorCodes.INVALID_DATA_TYPE,
                            message: errorMessages.FRIEND_NAME_INVALID_DT
                        },
                        required: {
                            errorCode: errorCodes.REQUIRED_FIELD,
                            message: errorMessages.FRIEND_NAME_REQUIRED
                        },
                        len: {
                            errorCode: errorCodes.LENGTH_MISMATCH,
                            message: errorMessages.FRIENDS_NAME_LENGTH
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        custom: (data) => {
            if (data.password === data.confirm_password) {
                return null;
            } 
            return {
                errorCode: errorCodes.VALUES_MISMATCH,
                message: errorMessages.PASSWORD_CONFIRM_PASSWORD_MISMATCH
            };
        }
    },
    errors: {
        type: {
            errorCode: errorCodes.INVALID_DATA_TYPE,
            message: errorMessages.REGISTER_USER_INVALID_DT
        },
        required: {
            errorCode: errorCodes.REQUIRED_FIELD,
            message: errorMessages.REGISTER_USER_REQUIRED
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output, I am getting:

```
true
12
true
9
13
13
undefined
```

expected output:

```
true
12
true
9
-----> I expect json object with errorCode and message to be printed here
```

Comment: have you typeof schema.errors is undefined . try to console schema.errors and its type

Comment: `fields[key] === undefined` might be better as `typeof fields[key] === "undefined"`
This returns "undefined" because notAFunction; is not defined. There may be other issues.

Comment: @RahulRana scfhema.errors is not undefined right now.

Answer (score 0):

You too, are **not** returning a value at the end of the function (or as you put it, "using the return keyword when calling the function").

After the `console.log('13')` (the last statement of `checkSchema`), you are not returning anything. To put it in a better way, your recursive function *has no base case for when `schema.hasOwnProperty('schema')` is false.*

EDIT: In fact, `checkSchema` does not return a value at all. You are returning values from the anonymous function used in `forEach` but not from `checkSchema`. Reverting to the `for` statement instead of `forEach` should fix it, but the no base case problem will remain unless you *want* `undefined` to be returned for that case. Even if you do, an explicit return would be better.

The second last statement printed out to the logs is "`13`", after which your initial `checkSchema` function call returns, assigning the supposed return value to `x`, the value of which is then logged. But since nothing is returned after `13` is logged, the value of `x` is undefined.

Comment: Then how do I return from checkSchema instead of forEach?

Comment: As detailed in my answer, use your commented out `for` statement instead of the `forEach`.

Comment: If I use for statement then key === 'custom' will always be false as custom will have a value of function and it is neglected (I don't know why?)

Comment: I don't use JavaScript, but from the usage of your current `forEach` statement, I'd recommend you try `for (key in Object.keys(schema.schema))`.

Comment: That leads me to other errors like `Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined.`

Comment: That's because you don't have a base case as stated in my answer. You would want to return an empty schema instead of `undefined` at the end of `checkSchema`.

Comment: Please give me some time, I will create a JSFiddle and then explain you the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from `checkSchema` function. So `const x = checkSchema(fields, schema);` will always evaluate to undefined.

Whatever you are returning from this `checkSchema` function, you are actually returning that from the callback of `Object.keys().forEach`. So whenever you return anything from the callback of `Object.keys().forEach`, that does not mean you are returning that from `checkSchema`

Comment: Then how do I return from checkSchema instead of forEach?

Comment: @Vishal Use `for (const key in schema.schema) {` instead of `Object.keys(schema.schema).forEach(function (key) {`

Comment: I have tried to use that but problem with that is : when I compare key === 'custom', it will always return false as custom will have a value of function and it is neglected(I don't know why?)

Comment: @Vishal No. `key` will always be a string i.e. `typeof key=string` and `schema.schema[key]` will  be a function. i.e. `typeof schema.schema[key] = function`

Comment: Yes you are right. Key will always be a string. But value of schema.schema.custom will be a function. So, for loop somehow ignores this key altogether. I don't know why????

Comment: @Vishal If key will be always be `string` then how `key === 'custom'` will always evaluate to `false`. Not making much sense to me.

Comment: I am creating a demo on plunker. When I am done, I will show you the problems.

Comment: @Vishal Your demo does not reflect your question. it output `true, 12, true, 13` but your question's output is `true, 12, true, 9,`

Comment: @Vishal `key === 'custom'` is not false. Your `key === 'custom'` is never executed actually. Because if you use `for` instead of `forEach` then you return some value already.

Comment: Sorry, It was a lunch break in my company, so I had to go out. Anyways, I changed some properties while testing, so the output of demo and output of my question, does not match. Now, i changed it to the same way as it was before. So, now you can see the output as mentioned in question.

Comment: @Vishal So when i use `for` instead of `forEach` in this demo code, i get the desired result. Now since you are returning some value i.e.(`return sendError(innerSchema, 'len');`) therefore the `checkSchema` stops further execution and `if(key === 'custom')` statement is never executed. `key === 'custom'` does not evaluate to `false`. It is simply not executed. You got the point?

Comment: No, its not OK. I can reproduce the scenario. Just go to the function onButtonClick(), and then change value of alias to `ac`. Then change value of password to `12345678`. Please don't change confirm_password. Now, run the project. The expected bhavior is that I should see an error saying that password and confirm_password does not match. But instead I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

> I have seen too many questions that have same problem as mine, but
>   everywhere I see that the problem is that they are not using return
>   keyword when calling the function. So, please don't mark it as
>   duplicate.

The truth is this really is one of those duplicates. So here are some pointers:

```
function checkSchema(fields, schema) {
    console.log(schema.hasOwnProperty('schema'));
    if (schema.hasOwnProperty('schema')) {
        Object.keys(schema.schema).forEach(fnElementJob);
    }
    console.log('13');
}
```

I've left the passed function to `forEach` because it is irellevant for the return of this function. Do you see any return statements in there? I don't thus JavaScript does it for you!

```
function checkSchema(fields, schema) {
    console.log(schema.hasOwnProperty('schema'));
    if (schema.hasOwnProperty('schema')) {
        Object.keys(schema.schema).forEach(fnElementJob);
    }
    console.log('13');
    return undefined; // implicit return for the last line of every function
}
```

A `return` in `fnElementsJob` jost stops that function so that `forEach` can continue with the next element. I see that you sometimes return a value like `return result;`. This value will be discarded since `forEach` is for side effects only and does not keep the returned values.

As for some of your `if` I suggest you always consider the alternative. Imagine this code:

```
if (innerSchema.type === Array && innerSchema.hasOwnProperty('unique')
    && innerSchema.unique && (new Set(fields[key])).size !== fields[key].length) {
    console.log('10');
    return sendError(innerSchema, 'unique');
}

if (innerSchema.type === String && innerSchema.hasOwnProperty('match')
    && innerSchema.match instanceof RegExp && !innerSchema.match.test(fields[key])) {
    console.log('11');
    return sendError(innerSchema, 'match');
}
```

If you think you are handling all cases you can do it like this:

```
if (innerSchema.type === Array && innerSchema.hasOwnProperty('unique')
    && innerSchema.unique && (new Set(fields[key])).size !== fields[key].length) {
    console.log('10');
    return sendError(innerSchema, 'unique');
} else if (innerSchema.type === String && innerSchema.hasOwnProperty('match')
    && innerSchema.match instanceof RegExp && !innerSchema.match.test(fields[key])) {
    console.log('11');
    return sendError(innerSchema, 'match');
} else {
    throw new Error('Unhandled case');
}
```

In general your code seems very complex. You are in desperate need of abstracting out so that your functions becomes easier to reason about. This is probably the main reason this code has become a SO question.

I also suggest you learn how to use a debugger instead of relying on printing out hints to which branch in the code has been visited. If you could set a break point and step through the code seeing what the variables were and the return was you wouldn't be posting such an obvious duplicate on Stack Overflow. If you abstract and use a debugger your life will become easier. It also allow you to make more complex code, but don't do that. Updating a 100 line function is not fun.